# ASP.net Core add reference to assembly

Tags: mysql, asp.net, reference

I'm trying to connect my ASP.net core web application with my MySql-server, but when I try to open the connection:

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("Server=MySqlServer; database=todoDb; UID=root; password=...");
connection.Open();
```

I'm getting this error in the second line:

```
The type 'DbConnection' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
```

I know that I need to add a reference to my project, but when I try to do this in my ASP.net core application the "Assemblies" menu option is not there.

(I don't have enough reputation so I'm not allowed to put pictures in my question(just click the 1)) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Q6aT.png)

My question is how do i add a reference to an assembly in ASP.net core?

Comment: Just as before, using nuget.

Answer (score 0):

Try both:

1. You can download it in your system then try to browse it from your system, then you may able to add assembly.
2. Try to add assembly from your another from which is in your system.